# ETS table creation error

Tags: elixir

I've run into a problem when trying to create and ETS table based on records. The code is taken from the book `Introducing Elixir`.

Here's the record:

```
defmodule Planemo do
    require Record
    Record.defrecord :planemo, [name: nil, gravity: 0, diameter: 0, distance_from_sun: 0]
end
```

Now if a table is created as follow, it succeeds:

```
planemo_table = :ets.new(:planemos,[:named_table, {:keypos, Planemo.planemo(:name) + 1}])
```

In another example, the author uses the following syntax (`__record__`) and it fails:

```
planemo_table = :ets.new(:planemos,[:named_table, {:keypos, Planemo.__record__(:index, :name) + 1}])
```

Error:

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Planemo.__record__/2 is undefined or private
    Planemo.__record__(:index, :name)
    planemo_storage.ex:6: PlanemoStorage.setup/0
```

I first thought that maybe `__record__` was deprecated in Elixir 1.3.2, but I've not been able to find any trace of it. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That book seems to be very old. Many of the Records features including `__record__` were [removed on 24 May 2014](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/commit/007571e9797471c269408dd67d1fa4ce3c9cc8e5) and the change was part of [Elixir 0.14 which was released on 17 June 2014](http://elixir-lang.org/blog/2014/06/17/elixir-v0-14-0-released/).

Comment: Yes, it's old, now that I check it. Uses version 0.13, for God's sake!